# Requirejs with perfect-scrollbar jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

Let me begin by saying that I've only picked up RequireJS very recently, and I'm still trying to wrap my head around how it works.

I am trying to use [perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar), specifically the jQuery version.

My `index.js`:

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {
        'perfectScrollbar': {
            'deps': ["jquery"]
        }
    },
    paths: {
        'jquery': "lib/jquery-3.2.1.min",
        'perfectScrollbar': "lib/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min"
    }
});

require(["jquery", "perfectScrollbar"], function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".custom_scrollbar").perfectScrollBar();
    });
});
```

I get the following error in the console:

```
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).perfectScrollBar is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.js:15)
    at j (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
```

**EDIT:** Switching to jQuery 2.2.1 yields the following (similar) error:

```
index.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).perfectScrollBar is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.js:15)
    at i (jquery-2.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery-2.2.1.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.n.fn.ready (jquery-2.2.1.min.js:2)
    at index.js:14
    at Object.execCb (require.js:5)
    at b.check (require.js:5)
    at b.<anonymous> (require.js:5)
    at require.js:5
    at require.js:5
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `$(...).perfectScrollBar()` with a capital "B". The actual name of the plugin [as documented in the README](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar#jquery) is `$(...).perfectScrollbar()` with a lowercase "b".